# Redefining keys in Emacs on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs, elisp

I use my command keys as extra control keys on Mac OS X (and I believe the space cadet keyboards had this configuration). I want to emulate this on my Windows machines by switching `Alt` to `Ctrl` and the `Windows` key to `Alt` within Emacs. Is this possible? I found [this post](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html) which suggests something like

```
(setq w32-pass-lwindow-to-system nil 
      w32-pass-rwindow-to-system nil 
      w32-pass-apps-to-system nil 
      w32-lwindow-modifier 'super ;; Left Windows key 
      w32-rwindow-modifier 'super ;; Right Windows key 
      w32-apps-modifier 'hyper) ;; Menu key
```

to get `super` and `hyper` keys upon pressing the windows key. When I try to remap this to `'control` to test it out (but eventually I want it to be `meta` and `Alt` as `Ctrl`, as mentioned), `windows-e` still gets intercepted by Windows (XP) and opens Explorer, but seems like a good place to start? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for `w32-pass-lwindow-to-system`:

> Note that some combinations of the left "Windows" key with other keys are
> caught by Windows at low level, and so binding them in Emacs will have no
> effect.  For example, <lwindow>-r always pops up the Windows Run dialog,
> <lwindow>-<Pause> pops up the "System Properties" dialog, etc.  However, see
> the doc string of `w32-phantom-key-code'.

From the documentation for `w32-phantom-key-code`:

> Virtual key code used to generate "phantom" key presses.
> Value is a number between 0 and 255.
>
> Phantom key presses are generated in order to stop the system from
> acting on "Windows" key events when `w32-pass-lwindow-to-system' or
> `w32-pass-rwindow-to-system' is nil.

And as it also says on Xah's website:

> There's no way around that unless you use other tools such as AutoHotkey. Even so, it may not be possible to disable 【Win+l】 (lock window) and 【Win+u】 (easy access).

So it seems that if it doesn't work with the method he describes (which seems right), **you should look into AutoHotKey**.

Comment: +1. I took the liberty of bolding what I considered the important part.